# Syntax error in IE using ES6 arrow functions

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6

I have this piece of JavaScript code

```
price = price.replace(/(.*)\./, x => x.replace(/\./g,'') + '.')
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, however IE gives me an syntax error pointing at `=>` in my code.

Is there a way to use ES6 arrow syntax in IE?

Comment: Until IE wants to become happy, use anonymous method inside `replace`.

Comment: Use a transpiler or write ES5 code in the first place.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

IE doesn't support ES6, so you'll have to stick with the original way of writing functions like these.

```
price = price.replace(/(.*)\./, function (x) {
  return x.replace(/\./g, '') + '.';
});
```

Also, related: [When will ES6 be available in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645891/when-will-es6-be-available-in-ie)

Answer (score 4):

Internet explorer doesn't support [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) yet. You can check the browsers supporting arrow functions [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions).

The method to solve it would be to make a good old regular callback function :

```
price = price.replace(/(.*)\./, function (x) {
    x.replace(/\./g,'') + '.';
}
```

This would work in every browser.