# Jquery Form Submission not working on IE11?

Tags: jquery

Im handling a form submission through jquery and it works well on ALL browsers except IE, in which the page stays completely static. on.mouseenter effects added are also not working in this browser.

I already included the head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

on jquery i got:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
$('.imigi1').on('mouseenter', () => {$('.imigi1').removeClass('img-fluid');         $('.imigi1').addClass('expandimage2')})
$('.imigi1').on('mouseleave', () => {$('.imigi1').removeClass('expandimage2');
$('.imigi1').addClass('img-fluid')} )      

$('#maintitle').on('mouseenter', () => {$(event.currentTarget).removeClass('imgtxttitle2'); $(event.currentTarget).addClass('imgtxttitle1');})
$('#maintitle').on('mouseleave', () => {$(event.currentTarget).addClass('imgtxttitle2'); $(event.currentTarget).removeClass('imgtxttitle1');} )    



$('#form01').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var email = $('#email').val();

        $.ajax({
            url:'https://formspree.io/mwrywazx',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                 _replyto:email,
                 email:email,
            },
            dataType:"json",
            success:function() {
                console.log('success'); 
                $('#confirmation').toggleClass('invisible');

            }   
        });         
    });


})
```

Comment: `() => { }` syntax (arrow functions) doesn't work in Internet Explorer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error in IE using ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110022/syntax-error-in-ie-using-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because you're using arrow functions. IE11 doesn't support them. Use function functions instead.

See ["Arrow function" not working in IE, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/arrow-function-not-working-in-ie-why)

for example:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      // <inner functions here>
   });
```