# querySelectorAll/forEach not working in IE11

Tags: javascript

Trying to make some good accessible cards but having trouble with IE11 (no surprise).  Pretty sure I'm missing something obvious?  I know it is an issue with the js but brain is having trouble getting in to gear :/

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');  
Array.prototype.forEach.call(cards, card => {  
    let down, up, link = card.querySelector('h4 a');            
    card.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    card.onmousedown = () => down = +new Date();
    card.onmouseup = () => {
        up = +new Date();
        if ((up - down) < 200) {
            link.click();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: try `document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(card=>...`

Comment: IE doesn't support the arrow functions

Comment: What's the error message you are getting in IE11?

Comment: IE11 is a dead browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the basic function

Internet explorer dont support es6 syntax(arrow function)

Check this links out for more

[IE array function stack overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110022/syntax-error-in-ie-using-es6-arrow-functions/40110178#:~:text=Internet%20explorer%20doesn%27t%20support,browsers%20supporting%20arrow%20functions%20here.&text=This%20would%20work%20in%20every%20browser.)

[github discussion](https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/issues/56)

Comment: @Lee if you find this helpful please consider marking this as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Ah yeah, forgot IE11 was no good with es6.  Full hand it is!  I hate it when a project demands IE support.

```js
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(cards, function (card) {
  var down,
      up,
      link = card.querySelector('h4 a');
  card.style.cursor = 'pointer';

  card.onmousedown = function () {
    return down = +new Date();
  };

  card.onmouseup = function () {
    up = +new Date();

    if (up - down < 200) {
      link.click();
    }
  };
});
```